# How to get a correct mean after using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, mean

I have a dataframe of a step counter. It has a column M_DATE (dd-mm-yy hh-mm-ss) that I set to date time. It also has a column M_STEPS that contains the number of steps that are done.

I split the date column in to several columns with also a column named "day_of_week". This one determines what the name of the day is was.

I wanted to use a groupby function on the day_of_week and wanted to have the mean per Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc. But I get an answer that doesn't look right.

I have tried

to got the name of the days I did:

```
df['day_of_week'] = df['M_DATE'].dt.day_name()
```

then I did :

```
df.groupby('day_of_week')['M_STEPS'].mean()
```

I hoped that it would group for example all the Mondays and then give me the mean of the amount of steps taken on Mondays. But the outcome is some is a very big number that I cannot make sense of.

The strange thing is when I use:

```
df.groupby('day_of_week')['M_STEPS'].sum()
```

it does give me a correct number.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit

Here I copied and pasted the df.head()

```
        M_ID    M_DATE  M_CALORIES  M_STEPS M_DISTANCE  M_METS  M_WEEK  M_WEEKDAY   M_HOUR  M_MINUTE    year    month   day day_of_week
        0   27  2016-01-24 00:00:00 1   0   0.0 10  3   1   0   0   2016    1   24  Sunday
        1   28  2016-01-24 00:01:00 1   0   0.0 10  3   1   0   1   2016    1   24  Sunday
        2   29  2016-01-24 00:02:00 1   0   0.0 10  3   1   0   2   2016    1   24  Sunday
        3   30  2016-01-24 00:03:00 1   0   0.0 10  3   1   0   3   2016    1   24  Sunday
        4   31  2016-01-24 00:04:00 1   0   0.0 10  3   1   0   4   2016    1   24  Sunday
```

Comment: Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have:

```
day_of_week  M_steps
Monday        1
Monday        2
Tuesday       1
Tuesday       3
```

then `df.groupby('day_of_week')['M_STEPS'].mean()`:

```
Monday 1.5
Tuesday 2
```

and `df.groupby('day_of_week')['M_STEPS'].sum()`:

```
Monday 3
Tuesday 4
```

This is groupby doing, probably the dataframe is sorted differently. Could you add your original dataframe to your example?

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Stackoverflow so I have to find out how I can add the dataframe to the example.

Comment: Just built your table here, we do not need the full dataframe, just the rows or columns which are important for us. in python you can copy paste for example: `dataframe.head()` here..

Comment: Okay. I removed a couple of columns and copied and pasted it. Hope I did that right

Comment: after seeing your dataframe, groupby should work, are you sure you looking for mean and not for the sum?

Comment: My first assignment was to get the sum of the steps per day. The results I got where correct. I checked this with the total steps in de dataframe.

Comment: For example I got for the Monday a total number of 413070 steps. The data consists of 36 weeks, so 36 Mondays. So I expect something around 11000 steps as a mean for the Mondays. Instead I got 5.408165 .